# Investigate AWS SNS without any side effects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

As you know, we can publish to an SNS events via those channels:

- HTTP
- HTTPS
- Email
- Email-JSON
- Amazon SQS
- AWS Lambda
- Platform application endpoint
- SMS

Now let's say I want to test a published messsage. 
According to the list, I can use a "[*request catcher service*](https://requestbin.com/)" for `Http/s` requests, but sometimes the info is too confidential to be published to third party services.

The email solution is too side effecty. Also writing lambda involves writing code.
Connecting an SQS to inspect messages is causing me to create a special SQS just for testing...

**Question:**

Is there any option to submit to an SNS and to inspect the message in logs or something like that? Or am I limited only to this list? I'm talking only for dev purposes.

Comment: Set up your own "request catcher service"? A tiny little service that takes the HTTP request and logs/stores it to a DB would be quite quick to put together.

Comment: @ceejayoz this requires that the SNS will have access to my local "request catcher service" in my local pc. For security reqsons and network infrastructure - it's not possible.

Comment: You could use some cloudwatch metrics to verify around the items, but not the entire message itself. I've also used Localstack for some integration tests and captured the message, Localstack can also spin up (for example) an SQS you can connect to the SNS topic for heavier integration tests to verify the messages that way. But in terms of pure AWS solutions I think you're detailed them

Comment: A lambda function that just logs the incoming event it's much overhead. `exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
}`

Comment: @JasonWadsworth nice idea (simple in-window-edited lambda with node that shows indented json).

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Does this cloudwatch metrics show _any_ data from the message body ? or is it just a signal for a new message arrival?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I didn't say it had to be local. Host it on AWS.

Comment: I find that creating and subscribing an Amazon SQS queue to be quite easy, and it captures the messages for later review. As to "causing me to create a special SQS just for testing", you're going to need to setup _something_ for testing anyway.